# how to set a theme for ttkthemes for python3 in windows10?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to style my `tkinter` GUI with some theme from ttkthemes.
I have found this code :

```
from ttkthemes import ThemedStyle
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

app = tk.Tk()
app.title('App')

style = ThemedStyle(app)
style.set_theme("black")

tktext = tk.Label(app, text=" tk Label")
tktext.pack()
tkbutton = tk.Button(app, text="tk Button")
tkbutton.pack()

text = ttk.Label(app, text=" ttk Label")
text.pack()
button = ttk.Button(app, text="ttk Button")
button.pack()

app.geometry('200x200')

app.mainloop()
```

in this topic : 
[Python - How do I add a theme from ttkthemes package to a guizero application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51697858/python-how-do-i-add-a-theme-from-ttkthemes-package-to-a-guizero-application#)

but I have a problem with that and that's when I run the program the theme doesn't cover whole root windows and just the buttons or labels from `ttk` are taking the theme (using windows10).I have tried in some other codes and everytime the same problem.
What's Problem with that?
[ttktheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvhiK.png)

Answer (score 1):

Themes only apply to widgets from the ttk module. For widgets not in ttk, such as the text widget, you have to configure them individually.

Comment: but i have many advs that they were effected completely with theme. like the one in this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51697858/python-how-do-i-add-a-theme-from-ttkthemes-package-to-a-guizero-application#