# How to add theme/style to GUIZERO python3 package

Tags: python, tkinter, themes, guizero

So I'm trying to build a small app, and I really enjoy the Guizero package and it's easy, event-driven programming.

The only thing it seems to lack is a method to implement theme changes, so it looks really outdated at the moment. Is there a way to apply Tkinter packages or something?

Below is some code I've tried, and it even prints 'vista' out correctly, but it doesn't seem to implement the actual theme change.

```
from tkinter import *
from guizero import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

app = App(title="Application Name", layout="grid", height=200, width=600)  # Random app name
app.tk.iconbitmap("someicon.ico")  # I got this to work

s=ttk.Style()

#app.ttk.Style().theme_use('default')

print(s.theme_names())  # loads themes
print(s.theme_use())  # shows potential theme names ('winnative', 'clam', 'alt', 'default', 'classic', 'vista', 'xpnative')

s.theme_use('vista')
print(s.theme_use())  # prints 'vista'

app.style = s

print(app.style.theme_use()) # prints 'vista'

app.display()
```

Comment: `guizero` is using `tkinter` widgets, not `ttk` widgets, so they do not support theme styling.

Comment: @acw1668 , but as you can impliment tk onto Guizero (app.tk.iconbitmap("someicon.ico") ) and ttk onto tk, can you not 'tunnel' tkk onto guizero through tk somehow?

Comment: As I said, `guizero` is not using `ttk` widgets, so what you have done on theme styling does not work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - How do I add a theme from ttkthemes package to a guizero application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51697858/python-how-do-i-add-a-theme-from-ttkthemes-package-to-a-guizero-application)

Comment: @acw1668, I've seen that one and was hoping to keep using Guizero, as its a nice little package. If it's not got themes, though, I guess I'll unfortunately have to use TkInter.

Oh, well. Thank you for your help

Comment: You could use functions and loops to create you own styling. Ps you  don't need to use tk.iconbitmap any more. Version 1.2.0 of Guizero added a .icon  property for app. If you still want to use Guizero let me know and a can give you an example.

Comment: @PurpleLlama , please give me an example, it's been driving me nuts and I've been test running stuff to make it TKinter compatible.
I will use your icon advice, too. Thank you.

Comment: I added a answer it's fairly basic but tell me if you don't understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not ttk but you can still style what you want.

```
from guizero import *

app = App()
#app.icon="images/Icon.ico"
#Changes in version 1.2.0
#https://lawsie.github.io/guizero/changelog/



#.icon does not work on Window()
#you will need to use WindowsName.tk.iconbitmap("Icon.ico")
#when creating a second window or more 

def do_nothing():
    print("Button was pressed")
    
#tkinter  widget Properties
#https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_gui_programming.htm        
def elementsName(Name):
    #example of Guizero property
    #Name.bg='green'
    #these are button widget properties 
    Name.tk.config(width=5,
                   height=1,
                   borderwidth=0,
                   relief="groove",
                   activeforeground='darkgray',
                   activebackground='green',
                   highlightthickness=0,
                   #highlightcolor="blue",
                   bg='blue',
                   fg='orange'
                   )



button1 = PushButton(app,text='button', command=do_nothing)
button1.text_size=15
button2 = PushButton(app,text='button2', command=do_nothing)
button2.text_size=15

#do no use '' or "" inside this tuple.
buttonsNames=(button1,button2)


#works for group of elements doesn't
#work on single elements/widgets
for x in buttonsNames:
    elementsName(x)



#How to style just one elements/widget
'''
using tkinter config
WidgetsName.tk.config(property1,
                      property2,
                      property3,
                      )
                      
                      
                      
Using Guizero to list each property separately
WidgetsName.text_size=12
WidgetsName.text_color= 'gray'
'''

app.display()
```

Comment: This is great! 
I have the artisitic skills of a potato, though, so is there some form of 'cheat sheet' somewhere? 
E.g, 'Vista is Highlightthickness 3, font 6, groove 2,...' ?
So i can quickly impliment already-appreciated styles?

Comment: This is for more of creating you own themes. I'm unaware of where to find a cheat sheet about all the default style info on windows or any other operating system. You may not even need it. Can you give an image of what you are trying to do? I see very few example of  modern apps using the built in themes .

Comment: I just want an app to look 'modern' such as with a rounded border, buttons, etc.
Your code snippet above has helped immensely, but I also have other things I want.

I generally want someone to use a GUI I made and think 'wow, it looks slick and modern' instead of base 1990 GUI.

Comment: If you can't get buttons to look the way you want you can always use images. There are plenty of free sites so you don't even need to know any image editing software.